# how to call a method declared in another class (c++)

Tags: c++, class

I have two classes: Question and Answer. I've properly constructed them and implemented most of the functions properly, (this is for school, so there are set methods I have to implement).

Within the class Question, there is this method:

```
class Question {
   Answer getAnswer(int index) const;
}
```

I was wondering how I was supposed to call this and how this affected the scope. Does this mean that getAnswer is only available to objects of Question?

I tried to do the following, but got an error message in the compiler.
`objectOfAnswer.getAnswer(index);`

I got the following error message: "no member named 'getIndex' in 'Answer'"

Comment: So did you provide a class member definition for `Answer::getIndex(int index) const;` and is it seen in the `Question`code?

Comment: Yes, what you posted so far means exactly that: "getAnswer is only available to objects of Question".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question.hxx:

```
#include "Answer.hpp"

class Question{

   public:

   Answer getAnswer(int index) const;
}
```

Question.cxx:

```
#include "Question.hpp"

Answer Question::getAnswer(int index)
{
   return new Answer();
}
```

main.cxx:

```
#include "Question.hpp"

int main()
{
  Answer answer = Question::getAnswer(5);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you already have an Answer object, there is no reason to try to call the getAnswer(index) of an Answer object since you already have the answer.

If you want to get another answer of the question, consider code like this:

```
answer.getQuestion()->getAnswer(anotherIndex);
```

(I'm assuming here that getQuestion() returns a pointer to the question)

Of course, then you need to actually implement the getQuestion() method in the Answer class and this requires keeping a pointer to the Question in the Answer class.